# Como dizer «sting operation» em português?

Tags: tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

Numa investigação policial ou jornalística, uma [*sting operation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sting_operation) é uma operação ardilosa com o objetivo de aliciar um suspeito a revelar as suas atividades ilegais. Por exemplo, um agente faz-se passar por comprador de droga para expor um traficante; ou por recetador de objetos roubados para expor um  ladrão; ou por criança num chat para expor um pedófilo.

Não conheço nenhum nome em português para estas operações. Encontrei no Google a tradução literal, [*operação ferrão*](https://www.google.pt/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=%22opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20ferr%C3%A3o%22&oq=%22opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l4.3997j0j4), que só quem conheça o significado do original inglês compreenderá. E depois de eliminarmos falso positivos e repetições, ficamos apenas com dez ocorrências.

Já existe algum nome em português para estas operações? Como poderíamos exprimir a ideia numa expressão curta e compreensível? Aqui ficam dois exemplos de uso:

> A polícia apanhou o traficante numa/num ________________.
>
> Ministro pedófilo exposto numa/num ______________.

Comment: "operação com agente infiltrado"? Foi a única coisa que me veio à ideia.

Comment: @Jactinto Boate!! ;) `A polícia apanhou o traficante numa boate.` e `Ministro pedófilo exposto numa boate.`

Comment: @ANeves Boate?! Só conhecia boate = boite! Onde é que visto isso?

Comment: Sim, era [boîte](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/boate)... :p

Comment: operação de infiltração, agente infiltrado, no Brasil consta da LEI Nº 12.850, DE 2 DE AGOSTO DE 2013

Comment: No Brasil isso se chama *flagrante armado* (*armado* no sentido de *arranjado*, *planejado*). Não conhecia a expressão em inglês, então não tenho certeza se a correspondência é total, mas pela sua descrição parece ser isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não conhecia *flagrante armado*, mas é auto-explicativo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não queres escrever uma resposta? Com exemplos reais? A correspondência não tem de ser perfeita (correspondências perfeitas são provavelmente raras). A tua sugestão parece aplicar-se bem aos meus exemplos e às minhas frases inacabadas.

Comment: @bfavaretto - Flagrante armado, ou, mais simplesmente, *armação*. Quando envolve a colocação de "provas" falsas, diz-se que o objeto em questão foi plantado: *a polícia **plantou** um baseado no carro do suspeito, para justificar o flagrante*.

Answer (score 3):

Encontrei os termos **flagrante preparado** ou **flagrante provocado** [nesta discussão](http://www.direitonet.com.br/artigos/exibir/6154/Flagrante-preparado-e-flagrante-esperado) sobre a legalidade de ambos. Este tipo de flagrante é definido como:

> Podemos dizer que existe *flagrante preparado* ou *provocado*
> quando o agente, policial ou terceiro, conhecido como provocador,
> induz o autor à prática do crime, viciando a sua vontade, e, logo em
> seguida, o prende em flagrante.
>
> ...
>
> a ocorrência do crime só surge em razão da provocação daquele que pretende
> utilizar a prisão em flagrante.

É citado ainda o **flagrante esperado**, definida como:

> Com relação ao *flagrante esperado*, pode-se entender sua ocorrência
> quando uma autoridade policial ou terceiro previamente informado
> acerca de um crime, trata de promover diligências a fim de prender o
> agente que poderá praticar o crime, sendo a prática da autoridade
> policial ou de terceiro apenas a espera da ocorrência do crime, sem
> qualquer provocação.

No caso que citaste na pergunta, de uma criança se expor em um chat a um pedófilo, creio que seria possível classificá-lo como um *flagrante esperado*, enquanto no outro caso, onde um agente policial se passa por um consumidor de drogas seria um *flagrante preparado*.

Comment: Como será que os flagrantes provocado/preparado e esperado se relacionam com o flagrante armado sugerido pelo bfavaretto?

Comment: @Jacinto acho que flagrante armado é mais informal e acaba sendo ambíguo entre esses dois sentidos.

Answer (score 1):

Abaixo listo algumas expressões que têm registro de uso no português brasileiro.

### 1. Operação policial

A expressão em si não carrega o sentido de *ardil* presente no inglês, mas muitas vezes isso está implícito no contexto ou explícito no corpo da reportagem. Como sempre há um certo sigilo em torno dessas operações, a expressão genérica cai bem.

### 2. Flagrante armado

Essa expressão aparece com alguma frequência na imprensa brasileira, quase sempre em torno da [discussão da legalidade desse tipo de operação](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/cotidian/ff02059806.htm) (segundo a lei brasileira, certas operações desse tipo acabam por anular a tipificação jurídica do crime que se queria punir).

### 3. Operação com agente infiltrado

Essa opção, já sugerida pelo @JorgeB e pelo @AndréLyra, é longa, mas bastante utilizada – quando há um agente infiltrado, e pelo que entendi a definição em inglês é mais ampla.

### 4. Tocaia

É mais popular, coloquial, mas ocorre na imprensa, principalmente em veículos regionais ou de estilo mais sensacionalista.

Comment: Mas tu acabas por não explicar as várias opções, nem quais são as mais adequadas. Tocaia não sei o que é. Parece-me que há operações com agentes infiltrados que não são *sting* e vice-versa (um agente que se faz passar por criança num chat é um agente infiltrado?). Creio que uma *sting operation* facilmente cai na ilegalidade em Portugal também (a polícia não pode estimular o crime),  o que me parece mais uma indicação que é essa a melhor opção.

Comment: *Tocaia* ou *campana* é emboscada, quando a polícia se posta próxima a local por onde o suspeito terá de passar, para detê-lo; pode ou não envolver flagrante.